# Android - How can I choose and display image from within fragment?

Tags: java, android, image, android-intent, android-fragments

I've been trying to choose and display an image on my fragment but it doesnt seem to work.

My code below starts and takes me to my gallery but when I click on a picture my app crashes and gives me an error on the line:

```
 Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri);
```

with error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=131073, result=-1, data=Intent {
>   dat=content://media/external/images/media/19394 (has extras) }} to
>   activity {com.mycompany.e_planner/com.mycompany.e_planner.MyActivity}:
>   java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading
>   com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri
>   content://media/external/images/media/19394 from pid=29204, uid=10011
>   requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or
>   grantUriPermission()

Here's my code:

```
public class Venue1 extends Fragment {

private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

public Venue1() {
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_venue1, container, false);

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);

    return V;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        Uri uri = data.getData();

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri);
            // Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(bitmap));

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add permission to read external storage in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error is pretty self explanatory. You need to request the permission `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. Just add it to your [manifest file.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)

Comment: oops - thanks for your answer. I think when you're sat coding for 10+ hours that's what happens...